# JSF-Primefaces 6.0 Push

Tags: java, sockets, jsf, primefaces, push

i have a question.

do i need a new request to get the new value of a bean attribute? I want to refresh the outputtext by push without reloading the page.

```
<p:outputLabel value="PushString"/><h:outputText id="out" value="#{testController.pushString}" styleClass="display" />
<p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/imageStream" />
```

i have a form with an outputtext which should get the text from server by primefaces push.

PushEndpoint:

```
@PushEndpoint("/imageStream")
public class ImagePushEndpoint{     
    @OnMessage(encoders = {JSONEncoder.class})
    public String onMessage (String message){
        System.out.println("PushEndpoint: "+message);
        return message;
    }
}
```

And in the ManagedBean the eventBus publishes the String to the endpoint:

```
eventBus.publish("/imageStream", pushString);
```

But i have to reload the page to get the new Value of the String.

My ApplicationServer is an embedded Jetty 9.3.

Do i have to configure the webappContext for primefaces push?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
    <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
    <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime-native</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You added 3 tags and a versionnumber to your title without a real question. Can you improve that?